# Can we find subgroup of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ with order 2?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

We used the following idea: first get a set of Hamel basis for $\mathbb{R}$, secondly, divide it into two parts such that one set of the Hamel basis forms a group, the other one is just the former one with a representative element added. However, it's hard to prove the existence of the representative and the construction of the division is also ambigious.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Every non-zero element of $\Bbb R$ generates an infinite subgroup; the only finite subgroup is the trivial one.

Comment: $2x=0\iff x=0$.

Comment: Anon's comment is, in fact, the complete answer, yet I wonder why would you want to mess with Hamel basis and stuff...?

Comment: @DonAntonio Messing with Hamel bases and the description makes it seem like maybe the aim is actually to find a subgroup of index $2$ rather than order $2$. I'll leave it up to the OP to clarify if this is the case though.

Comment: Do you mean 'index' instead of 'order'? Also why would you want to deal with division?

Comment: @SimonMarkett Yes! And Alexander Gruber has also solved the problem. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There are no nontrivial elements in $\mathbb{R}$ with finite order.

If you're looking for a subgroup of *index* 2, you're not going to have much luck either.  If $H$ has index $2$ in $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathbb{R}/H$ is a group of order $2$, so for any $r\in \mathbb{R}$,  $2(rH)=(2r)H=H$.  But then we can simply take $r=s/2$ given any $s\in \mathbb{R}$ and conclude that $sH=H$.  Thus we have $\mathbb{R}\subseteq H$, a contradiction.

If you're into generalizations, by the way, note that we may easily adapt the above to prove that there are no subgroups of finite index in $\mathbb{R}$ at all (or, more generally, in any the additive group of any field of characteristic $0$).  (Even more generally, fixing an $n\in \mathbb{N}$, no group with the property that $\forall g\in G \exists h\in G : h^n=g$ may have a subgroup of index $n$; in particular, no ring in which $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is a unit may have an additive subgroup of index $n$.)

Comment: Any *divisible* group cannot have proper subgroups of finite index. Now what are these groups? Well, (abelian) groups in which you can divide! Formally, these are groups $G$ in which for every positive integer $n$ and every $g \in G$, there exists an $x \in G$ such that $nx = g$.